# multi selection like iOS picture in Flutter

Tags: flutter

multi selection like iOS picture in Flutter

How can I implement an UI with Flutter like the following video?

[image]

[image]

- There are tiles / Rectangles arranged.
- They are available for multiple selections.
- In this video, I just drug from [B] to [R] (like Picture-1), and [B] to [R] were selected (like Picture-2), even though I did not touch neither [F],[K],[P] nor [E],[J],[O].

what to do with GestureDetector?

And I also wonder whether this is possible with rectangle painted on Canvas?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this, [drag_select_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_select_grid_view):

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final controller = DragSelectGridViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(scheduleRebuild);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(scheduleRebuild);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: SelectionAppBar(
        selection: controller.value,
      ),
      body: DragSelectGridView(
        gridController: controller,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, selected) {
          return SelectableItem(
            index: index,
            selected: selected,
          );
        },
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 80,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void scheduleRebuild() => setState(() {});
}
```